# Stacking Parse push notifications with a CustomReceiver

Tags: android, push-notification

I'm trying to put together several notifications in one as does Whatsapp, using a custom ParsePushBroadcastReceiver but GcmBroadcastReceiver receive automatics pushes that I don't can manage.

Android Manifest:

```
            <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
<receiver
        android:name=".ws.ParseAppReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

GmcBroadcasstReceiver:

```
public final void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
ServiceUtils.runWakefulIntentInService(context, intent, PushService.class);
```

MyCustomReceiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if(! intent.getAction().equals("com.parse.push.intent.DELETE")) {

        JSONObject data = getDataFromIntent(intent);

        try {
            mStringMessage = data.getString("alert");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        NotificationsManager.getInstance(context).addMessageToArray(mStringMessage);


        mArrayMessages = NotificationsManager.getInstance(context).getPushMessages();

        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

        for(int i = 0; i < mArrayMessages.size(); i++) {
            inboxStyle.addLine(mArrayMessages.get(i));
        }

        String title = mArrayMessages.size() + "nuevas Notificaciones";

        Notification summaryNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_runator_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                .setGroup("example")
                .setGroupSummary(true)
                .build();

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
                NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, summaryNotification);

    } else {
        NotificationsManager.getInstance(context).clearArrayMessages();
    }

}
```

GmcBroadcasstReceiver receive a automatic push notification and MyCustomReceiver receive the equal notification then the app shows two pushes Notifications.

If any have idea please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are they using the exact same `NOTIFICATION_ID` ? Unless they do, there should be two notifications and not one. If you want one, make them use the same ID

Comment: Parse send a push_id but is distinct in each push notification

Comment: So wait, your current problem is that `GcmBroadcastReceiver` and `MyCustomReceiver` both receive the same notification, but due to using different `NOTIFICATION_ID` for them, they are shown as two same push notifications ?

Comment: My problem is that GcmBroadcastReceiver receive one Parse push notification that i dont can manage, and MyCustomReceiver receive the same notification that I can manage, then two notifications is show, my custom push notification and the Parse push notification

Comment: Are you handling the notifications from your own application or from other applications?

Comment: I receive pushes notifications from Parse

Comment: And my objective is stacking this pushes then i need MyCustomReceiver but the problem is that GmcBroadcastReceiver show the push too